# Invalid use of group function (For using count in select)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1138

I got an error output on my sql query with remarks " Invalid use of group function "

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT project,tbl_nif.POno,tbl_custmon.so, tbl_nif.matcode, tbl_nif.prodesc, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WEEK(MAX(plannedGI))+1=6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as `week 6`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WEEK(MAX(plannedGI))+1=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as `week 2`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WEEK(MAX(plannedGI))+1=3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as `week 3`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WEEK(MAX(plannedGI))+1=4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as `week 4` 
FROM tbl_nif,tbl_custmon,tbl_incoming 
WHERE tbl_nif.so=tbl_custmon.so AND tbl_nif.bill='521513' AND tbl_incoming.shipment!=tbl_custmon.shipment 
            AND plannedGI!='0000-00-00' 
GROUP BY tbl_custmon.so 
ORDER BY tbl_custmon.so) AS grid 
ORDER BY project ASC
```

If I not include the "count" in query, it will be show the output.

So, kindly please tell me an idea for this issue. 
Big Thanks!

**CONCLUSION**
Put "Max" function on query makes a natural "group by". 
So I put "Max" function inline with the other SELECT field. 
So the query will be like this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT project,tbl_nif.POno,tbl_custmon.so, tbl_nif.matcode, tbl_nif.prodesc, MAX(plannedGI),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WEEK(plannedGI)+1=6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as `week 6`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WEEK(plannedGI)+1=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as `week 2`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WEEK(plannedGI)+1=3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as `week 3`,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WEEK(plannedGI)+1=4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as `week 4`
FROM tbl_nif,tbl_custmon,tbl_incoming 
WHERE tbl_nif.so=tbl_custmon.so AND tbl_nif.bill='521513' AND tbl_incoming.shipment!=tbl_custmon.shipment 
            AND plannedGI!='0000-00-00' 
GROUP BY tbl_custmon.so
ORDER BY tbl_custmon.so) AS grid 
ORDER BY project ASC
```

And the output will show data that I need. 
Many thanks to you :)

Comment: Try to keep only one count column and remove remaining columns. If you dont get error then add one more count column. Then you will know exactly where u get error

Comment: Also i think you need to include following columns in your groupby clause project,tbl_nif.POno,tbl_custmon.so, tbl_nif.matcode, tbl_nif.prodesc

Comment: Hi AshReva! thanks for your advice..
but somehow it's still error with the same remark..

Comment: Can you give me schema of your tables?

Comment: In the count where is this column plannedGI coming from. You have not mentioned tablename from where it should pick the value. You should write tbl_custom.PlannedGI

Comment: I just do that, and still the same dude

Comment: Please don't strip error messages. The complete error message normally points to the exact part of the code where the error lies.

Comment: Wait i will get back to you in 5 min

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario , I just tell the error remark..the really issue is when I put count on my query.

Comment: The column project is in which table?

Comment: @user1875301 - Alright, if you think that coding is not as hard as it should, go ahead and develop without the aid of error messages. You'll indeed have more fun.

Comment: @AshReva I just found the conclusion, I will write later. Many thanks to you ! :)

Comment: Let me know so i can put that in my answer and may be you accept it if its ok

Comment: i think you put your answer in the answer section and accept it